# Recaptcha v2 error only in IE. 'MessageChannel' is undefined

Tags: internet-explorer, recaptcha

Clients have recently started reporting the following error when loading a page using recaptcha v2 in IE 11:

SCRIPT5009: 'MessageChannel' is undefined
File: recaptcha__en.js, Line: 253, Column: 69

The widget renders, although the checkbox appears to be disabled, then the widget is replaced with this message:

"Please upgrade to a supported browser to get a reCAPTCHA challenge.

Alternatively if you think you are getting this page in error, please check your internet connection and reload."

We are not having this error in Chrome.

Thanks for any ideas.

UPDATE: Security Update for Internet Explorer (KB 4343205) patch was published on 8/14/2018. I don't know if this is related or not. Recaptcha was working prior though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what version of IE the page is set to run to. I came across this same error when the page was set to IE9 with the following meta tag. I updated to 11 and it started working.

Comment: Thank you - that fixed it! Much appreciated!